# mod_rewrite и ошибки в лог-файле

Tags: регулярные-выражения, mod-rewrite

Доброго времени суток)
На сайте ссылки типа http://site.ru/main/ перенаправляются с помощью правила

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/$ /?index=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Все бы хорошо, но лог-файл на хостинге забит ошибками типа:

```
File does not exist: /html/site/main
```

И на это можно было бы положить, но хостер регулярно присылает сообщения о том, что очень много ошибок на сайте.
Можно ли решить эту проблему? Может правила mod_rewrite какое-нить другое нужно?:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on   RewriteRule
^favicon.ico$ - [F,L] RewriteRule
^robots.txt$ - [F,L]
```

ДОбавь это и ошибки пропадут